# Connecting to Azure AS Model using .Net ADOMD - Certificate Thumbprint method

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-analysis-services, adomd.net

I'm trying to connect to an Azure Analysis Services model using Adomd.Net (to run a query against the cube)
I'm basically following the steps here (although my AS server, model & App Registration are all pre-existing):

https://www.sanjaybhagia.com/2018/11/12/accessing-azure-analysis-services-models-using-net-core

However it uses a Secret key to establish the connection, which my organisation wants to avoid creating for service principals for audit reasons. So per the microsoft article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-service-principal

allegedly you can use the certificate thumbprint instead of an App secret:

> ...connection strings using the following syntax: app:AppID and password or **cert:thumbprint.**

However when i try this with the Thumbprint that i get from the 'Certificates & secrets' section of the app principal, i just get an error that

> Certificate with thumbprint ‘xxxx…’ count not be found

A sample of code is below. I can see many articles/examples of people using the Secret method successfully, but none using this thumbprint method. Thanks in advance
(FYI i'm using full .Net framework not Core)

```
        private static async Task GetDataFromAzureAnalysisService()
    {
        var servername = "asazure://northeurope.asazure.windows.net/myserver";
        var appId = "myappid@mytenantid";
        var authKey = "mythumbprint";
        var connectionstring = $"Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source={servername};User ID=app:{appId};Password=cert:{authKey};Persist Security Info=True;Impersonation Level=Impersonate";

        try
        {
            using (AdomdConnection connection = new AdomdConnection(connectionstring))
            { ...
```

[image]

Comment: Did you install the certificate on the client machine? The thumbprint is just a way of saying which certificate to use.

Comment: To my understanding, you need to create an App registration and assign a certificate to that. Using that certificate the security token can be obtained and that token can be included in to the connection string. Though the documentation says certificate thumbprint can be used not sure that works.